# ACF allow zero as a value

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, variables

I would like to have 0 to 5, and "n/a" as possible values, however this code will output "n/a" when I want it to output a zero. How can I get it to output "0"?

("n/a" is the placeholder if no value is set.)

```
Difficulty: <?php if(get_field('difficulty'))  { echo the_field('difficulty');} else { echo "n/a"; }  ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In PHP, `0 == false == [] == '' == null`. A simple check to check if a variable or condition has a value will return `false` if the value is equal to 0.

For `0` to return true as a valid value, you would need to make use of strict comparison by using the identical (*`===`*) operator. Just remember, if you use `===`, not only the value must match, but the type as well, otherwise the condition will return false. If your values are a string, you should use `'0'`, if they are integer values (*which I doubt as custom field values are strings as single values*), you should use `0`.

You can do the following check

```
$difficulty = get_field( 'difficulty' );
if (    $difficulty // Check if we have a valid value
     || '0' === $difficulty // This assumes '0' to be string, if integer, change to 0
) {
    $value = $difficulty;
} else {
    $value = 'n/a';
}
echo 'Difficulty: ' . $value;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
$some = get_field('difficulty')
if($some != '')  { echo $some;} else { echo "n/a"; }  
?>
```

`the_field` function is its self echo.

Comment: Your codition will fail with `0` as `0` is taken as an empty string. See my answer